# Handling click events of links rendered within markdown React component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, markdown

I'm using React and react-marked to render markdown within a component.

The markdown content is user defined and sometime contains links.

What would be the best method of intercepting the click events on the markdown links.  I could obviously use jQuery, but wondered if there is a more elegant way using react events?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the default link token rendering as described here: https://github.com/LinuxBasic/react-marked#overriding-renderer-methods

```
var marked = require('marked');
var renderer = new marked.Renderer();

renderer.link = (href, title, text) => {
    const interceptWithThisFunction = (e) => {
        console.log('click event caught', e);
    }
    return `<a onClick="interceptWithThisFunction" href="${href}" title="${title}">${text}</a>`;
}
```

Comment: Well, in the React world, there aren't any global functions, and even if there were, the function name would be minified in production, so the onClick function name wouldn't work at all...