# Adding functionality to user comments in markdown-like fashion with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coffeescript, markdown

I'm building an React app in which users create written guides which often reference pins on a map.  I'd like users to be able to reference the pins in markdown-like fashion inside their written guides so that the pins are highlighted when hovered over in the rendered version of the guide.

However, I can't figure out how to process the user generated text so that it can call functions in the react component that the text is rendering in.

I found a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048037/handling-click-events-of-links-rendered-within-markdown-react-component) asking about how to handle click events using [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) and am happy to follow a similar approach but I can't figure out how to get the function called in the onclick within the scope of my React component in coffeescript.

Here's the accepted answer from the link above:

```
var renderer = new marked.Renderer();
renderer.link = (href, title, text) => {
    renderer.link = (href, title, text) => {
        const interceptWithThisFunction = (e) => {
            console.log('click event caught', e);
        }
        return `<a onClick="interceptWithThisFunction" href="${href}" title="${title}">${text}</a>`;
    }
```

I'm confused about why this would work in es6... As, when I code this in coffeescript as shown below, I get: **Uncaught ReferenceError: interceptWithThisFunction is not defined.**

```
renderer = new marked.Renderer()
renderer.link = (href, title, text) ->
  interceptWithThisFunction = (e) ->
      console.log('click event caught', e)
  "<a onClick='interceptWithThisFunction' href='#' title='#{title}'>#{text}</a>"
```

Is this the right approach?  Is there a way for the onClick currently set to interceptWithThisFunction to call a function on my React component?

Answer (score 0):

I can't really find common "react-marked" library. So what I can assume, is that tokeniser can return JSX in this react flavoured marked, and then you can write something like:

```
renderer.link = (href, title, text) => {
renderer.link = (href, title, text) => {
    const interceptWithThisFunction = (e) => {
        console.log('click event caught', e);
    }
    return (
      <a onClick={interceptWithThisFunction} href={href}>{text}</a>
    );
}
```

If it is not the case, then I can only recommend to move function to window, and add onclick handler to the html, like `<a onclick="interceptWithThisFunction" ...`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bloomca!

I believe the library the original poster was referring to is [react-marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-marked) but the read-me borrows from the main [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) read-me so I think I missed the distinction!

Anyway, I think your interpretation is probably correct and I'll be investigating more tonight.